# why is this dataTables jQuery plugin (TableTools) not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools

I am trying to add the TableTools extension for the jQuery plugin dataTables. I have gotten it onto the site but the .swf file is not being included. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#balances').DataTable({
    tableTools: {
        "sSwfPath": "../_inc/content/current-loan-balances-report/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table );

$( tt.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper'); } );
```

The table's ID is balances. the sSwfPath is where it said to specify the path for the swf file, which I have done. When I load the page, it says the file isn't being found, and in the console it is showing a different path than the one specified above.

Comment: did you reference the plugin at the top of the html page? and if the console shows a different path than specified maybe try CTRL+R to see if it shows up

Comment: I have never referenced a .swf file. tried it using the script tag but that didn't work. didn't think it would but didn't know what else to try. could yo ugive me an example include path for this file type?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the way dataTables references the .swf file. It isn't referenced at the top of the page, but within the script for dataTables, and the problem I was having was due to the file structure I am using. I had to move the .swf file to the root folder, reference it there within the dataTables script, and it worked no problem!